'Range' filter not showing in report
I want to use the 'Range' function on a Created Date field in a report. See the image below for reference:

But I don't see the 'Range' function. See the image below:

Is there anyway to bring the 'Range' filter in the report?


Even without a range filter you can still add a range by using two filters on the created date and setting the max date as "less or equal" and the min date as "greater or equal" like in this screenshot.
This will give you a range of June 10, 2024 to June 14, 2024.
